# short assigned (final int) works but passing (final int) as parameter to short argument doesnt work

Tags: java

Check out the following code and please help

```
class ShortExample{
final int x=9;
int m=9;
short s=x; // works fine as it is a compile time constant
short ss=9; // also works as compiler handles it
// short sss=m; // doesn't work due to possible loss of precision

ShortExample.play(x); // why doesn't this work
ShortExample.play(9);  // why doesn't this work 

static void play(short s){
//do something
}


}
```

Here when i assign a final int value to the short variable, it compiles without and issue. But if i pass the same value as a parameter it gives the loss of precision compilation error. Shouldn't it work as it is a constant value?

Comment: ShortExample() where did you declared ?

Comment: Are you trying to call `play`?

Comment: Narrowing primitive conversion doesn't work in method invocation contexts. Read up on constant expressions for the rest.

Comment: If you are indeed trying to call `play`, @Pillar is spot on.

Comment: (by the way, @Pillar, you're doing a very good job finding duplicates, big kudos!)

Comment: Thank you @Pillar, that was exactly what i was asking. I had mis-typed and called the constructor instead of the method. If possible, please provide any links for reading up. I'm preparing for oracle certs and it will be massively helpful. Cheers :)